# Using OUTER JOIN with a WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two related tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicle (
  Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Vehicle (Id, Name) VALUES (1, 'Car');
INSERT INTO Vehicle (Id, Name) VALUES (2, 'Van');
INSERT INTO Vehicle (Id, Name) VALUES (3, 'Motorcycle');

CREATE TABLE Signal (
  Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  VehicleId INT NOT NULL,
  Reading INT,
  StartTime DATE
);
INSERT INTO Signal (Id, VehicleId, Reading, StartTime) VALUES (1, 1, 10, '2016-12-10');
INSERT INTO Signal (Id, VehicleId, Reading, StartTime) VALUES (2, 1, 15, '2017-01-10');
INSERT INTO Signal (Id, VehicleId, Reading, StartTime) VALUES (3, 1, 4, '2017-02-10');
INSERT INTO Signal (Id, VehicleId, Reading, StartTime) VALUES (4, 2, 4, '2017-03-10');
```

When I perform an OUTER JOIN like this, it behaves as expected:

```
SELECT v.Name, SUM(s.Reading)
FROM Signal s
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Vehicle v ON v.Id = s.VehicleId
GROUP BY v.Name

(actual and expected result):
Car | 29
Motorcycle | NULL
Van | 4
```

But when I add a WHERE condition like this, it no longer does what I expect:

```
SELECT v.Name, SUM(s.Reading)
FROM Signal s
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Vehicle v ON v.Id = s.VehicleId
WHERE StartTime > '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY v.Name

(actual result):
Car | 19
Van | 4

(expected result):
Car | 19
Motorcycle | NULL
Van | 4
```

Why do I not get the expected result when I add the WHERE condition, and how do I fix it?

Comment: What are you expecting? By adding WHERE StartTime > '2017-01-01' you are only getting 3/4 of your Signal data

Comment: Change `where` to `and` and it will work.  The where clause is eliminating the nulls generated by the outer join,  Basically your where clause is making your outer join behave like an inner join.

Comment: It's a duplicate of a duplicate. I would expect someone with over 3000 reputation points will know how to search stackoverflow.

Comment: The join happens first.  Because the result of the join has null for start time for motorcycle that record is filtered out.  You can do as other have suggested and move to the on clause or you can also select records with null in start time.

    SELECT v.Name, SUM(s.Reading)
    FROM Signal s
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN Vehicle v ON v.Id = s.VehicleId
    WHERE StartTime > '2017-01-01' Or StartTime Is Null
    GROUP BY v.Name

    Name (No column name)
    Car          19
    Motorcycle NULL
    Van           4

Comment: Just to add an alternative. You can also use COALESCE or ISNULL, such as: SELECT    v.Name, 
     SUM(s.Reading)
FROM    Signal AS s
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Vehicle AS v ON v.Id = s.VehicleId
WHERE    COALESCE(StartTime,'4000-01-01') > '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY   v.Name

Answer (score 0):

because `WHERE StartTime > '2017-01-01'` makey your outer join to an join and removes all entries wich are not in table Signal.

Move the where condition to the on clause:

```
SELECT v.Name, SUM(s.Reading)
FROM Signal s
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Vehicle v ON v.Id = s.VehicleId AND StartTime > '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY v.Name
```

BTW: The column name `StartTime` is a little bit confusing, because it looks like you have date and time part. Better name ist `StartDate`

Answer (score 0):

Move the `WHERE` condition to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT v.Name, SUM(s.Reading)
FROM Signal s
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Vehicle v
    ON v.Id = s.VehicleId AND
       StartTime > '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY v.Name
```

But normally `LEFT JOIN` seems to be more prevalent, so you could rewrite your query as this:

```
SELECT
    v.Name,
    SUM(s.Reading) AS reading_sum
FROM Vehicle v
LEFT JOIN Signal s
    ON v.Id = s.VehicleId AND
       s.StartTime > '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY v.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a right outer join so it's taking the Vehicle table and then joining to any matching records in the Signal table. The where clause is filtering the Signal table, therefore if there is no matching record in the Signal table for the Vehicle table to join on, it will be a NULL, then you use the where and are removing that result.

Perhaps what you want is to put the "StartTime > '2017-01-01'" in the ON cluse instead? Or perhaps you were looking to do a left outer join instead of a right.  Hard to say without knowing your intentions